# Reference Request: Local decomposition of GGP period integrals of cuspidal forms on unitary groups

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, automorphic-forms

*Setup*: Let $E/F$ be a CM-extension of global number fields. Let $(V,\phi)$ be an Hermitian space of dimension $n$ over $E$. Let $(V^{\flat}, \phi^{\flat})$ be a subspace of $V$ of dimension $n-1$ on which the restricted Hermitian form  $\phi^{\flat}$ from $\phi$ is nondegenerate. Consider the unitary group $G$ associated to $(V,\phi)$ and $H$ the unitary group associate to $(V^{\flat}, \phi^{\flat})$. We view $H$ as a subgroup of $G$.

Let $\mathbf{G} = G \times H$. Let $\pi$ (resp. $\sigma$) be an irreducible automorphic representation of $G(\mathbb{A}_F)$ (resp. $H(\mathbb{A}_F)$), and define $\Pi := \pi \otimes \sigma$. Let $\Phi \in \Pi$ be a cusp form on $\mathbf{G}$. Then we consider the **Gan-Gross-Prasad period integral**
$$
\mathcal{P}(\Phi) = \int_{H(F) \backslash H(\mathbb{A}_F)} \Phi(h) \mathrm{d}h,
$$
where $\mathrm{d}h$ is the Tamagawa measures on $H(\mathbb{A}_F)$.

**Goal: how to decompose the global integral $\mathcal{P}(\Phi)$ into a product of local Euler factors (local zeta integrals?)?**

**Attempt 1**: The famous Ichino-Ikeda formula provides for tempered $\Pi$, $\Phi \in \Pi$ and $\Phi^{\prime} = \Pi^{\vee}$ an explicit formula
$$
\dfrac{\mathcal{P}(\Phi)\mathcal{P}(\Phi^{\prime})}{(\Phi, \Phi^{\prime})} = (\ast) \cdot \mathcal{L}(\pi \times \sigma) \cdot \prod_{v} \dfrac{I(\Phi_{v}, \Phi_v^{\prime})}{\mathcal{L}(\pi_v \times \sigma_v) (\Phi_{v}, \Phi_v^{\prime})},
$$
where $\mathcal{L}(\pi \times \sigma)$ is an appropriate normalization of $L(1/2, \pi \times \sigma)$, and local matrix coefficients
$$
I(\Phi_{v}, \Phi_v^{\prime}) := \int_{H(F_v)} (\Pi_v(h_v, h_v)\Phi_{v}, \Phi_v^{\prime}) \mathrm{d} h_v.
$$
**But this is different from my goal since $\mathcal{P}(\Phi)$ and $\mathcal{P}(\Phi^{\prime})$ appear together in the formula, yet I hope to see only one individual $\mathcal{P}(\Phi)$**. Under some additional assumptions, $\mathcal{P}(\Phi)\mathcal{P}(\Phi^{\prime})$ can be $\mathcal{P}(\Phi)^2$. This means that by the Ichino-Ikeda formula, it seems that I can only decompose the **square of the period integral** into local matrix coefficients, but unable to do it for the period integral itself.

**Question (a)**: So do we have a way out of this issue?

*A cheating method?* Note that $\Phi^{\prime}$ is auxillary, so we hope to choose $\Phi^{\prime}$ such that
$$
\mathcal{P}(\Phi^{\prime}) \neq 0.
$$
Then we can simply dividing this period from both sides of the Ikeda-Ichino formula. Does such $\Phi^{\prime}$ exist? As the global Gan-Gross-Prasad for unitary groups is solved (in most of the interesting cases?), this is equivalent to require that the central $L$-value $L(s, \Pi^{\vee}) \neq 0$. But such a requirement is too strong?

**Attempt 2**: In the context of Jacquet, Piateski-Shapiro and Shalika, we consider the case of general linear groups: we take $G=\mathrm{GL}_{n+1}/E$ and $H=\mathrm{GL}_n/E$. Let $\pi$ (resp. $\sigma$) be a cuspidal automorphic representation of $G$ (resp. $H$) and  $\Pi = \pi \otimes \sigma$. For $\phi \in \Pi$, we have the global (Rankin-Selberg) period integral
$$
\lambda(\phi) := \int_{H(F) \backslash H(\mathbb{A}_F)} \Phi(h) \mathrm{d}h.
$$
Then by the theory of Whittaker models, we have the Whittaker function $W_{\Phi}$ attached to $\Phi$ and
$$
\lambda(\phi) = L(1/2, \pi \times \sigma) \prod_w \lambda_{w}^{\natural}(W_{\Phi,w}),
$$
where $\lambda_{w}^{\natural}$ is an appropriate normalization of the local integral
$$
\lambda_w(W_w) = \int_{N(E_w) \backslash H(E_w)} W_w(h) \mathrm{d}h.
$$

**Question (b) - a reference request**: does this story of Jacquet, Piateski-Shapiro and Shalika generalize to unitary groups setting?

**Question (c)**: Are the considerations in *Attempt 2* actually "reproving the Ichino-Ikeda formula"?

Comment: The whole point is that $\mathcal{P}(\Phi)$ need not be Eulerian; rather, the square of the absolute value is Eulerian. For $n = 3$, for example, this is a toric period integral a la Waldspurger, and in general there is not much one can say about the period itself, but once one takes the square of the absolute value of the period, then one can show (using the relative trace formula or the theta correspondence) that the resulting expression is Eulerian and can be written in terms of special values of $L$-functions.

Comment: In the GGP situation, we have local multiplicity one, so a global linear functional factors a product of local linear functionals.  However, you need to choose a way to normalize the factors.

Comment: @PeterHumphries Thank you so much! Is there any *"theoretical reason"* on why the "square of the absolute value is Eulerian yet the period itself is not"? Currently, I can only accept and memorize this phenomenon (from the Ichino-Ikeda and the Waldspurger's formula you mentioned), but I don't really understand why. Sorry for being so naiive. :(

Comment: @Kimball and thank you for your comment! By local multiplicity one, I can try to write $$ \mathcal{P}(\Phi) = C_{\Phi} \prod_{v} \mathcal{P}_v(\Phi_v) $$ for some constant $C_{\Phi}$ and *mysterious* local functionals $\mathcal{P}_v(\Phi_v)$. But to see how the local $L$-factors come into the game, it seems that we need an explicit description on what $\mathcal{P}_v(\Phi_v)$ really is locally. So there are two problems I am facing following your hints: (a) Find an appropriate model for $\Pi$ on $\mathbf{G}$. Maybe I need some model on auto reps on $G$ and $H$ and tensor them to get for $\Pi$?

Comment: @Kimball ... and (b) At least at unramified places, under the model constructed in (a), I hope to get computable $\mathcal{P}_v(\Phi_v)$, from which the desired local $L$-factor appears. I guess that these (a) and (b) procedures must have been considered by people before, as it is quite "canonical", but I couldn't find any preprints or publications. Hence, I am doubting whether (a) and (b) are practical or not. Moreover, by Prof. Humphries' comment, it seems that in nature, the **square** of the period produces $L$-factors. So maybe the entire (a) and (b) scheme is merely daydreaming. :(

Comment: After reading the hints in the comments, I have found and been trying to read Masaaki Furusawa's 1993 paper *"On L-functions for $\mathrm{GSp}(4) \times \mathrm{GL}(2)$ and their special values"* to get some ideas. and the naiive (a) and (b) scheme is cooked up when reading this paper.

Comment: @HetongXu one “theoretical reason” for the phenomenon of squares here is in the context of relative Langlands duality, the square of the period solves a deformation quantization problem while the period itself solves a geometric quantization problem, which is much less well behaved and typically depends on choices of polarization data and metaplectic corrections. From this point of view (on the Galois side) there’s a natural reason for the square to factorize and none for the period itself (cf my paper w Sakellaridis and Venkatesh, at least morally..)